# DNN "Page Settings" Dialog Appears Off-Screen on Longer Documents

Tags: css, jquery-ui, dotnetnuke, jquery-ui-dialog, dotnetnuke-7

As an admin, when I go to Edit Page -> Page Settings, a jQueryUI dialog appears for editing content.
When I have a longer document, the dialog falls off the screen, as if it's centering itself based on the document's middle, as opposed to the user's browser viewport. See my screen shot.

[image: screen shot]

I've tried hacks like adding a negative top-margin, but to no avail.
DNN version: DNN 07.02.02 (303)
jQuery version: 1.9.1
jQuery-UI version: 1.10.3

Anyone ever successfully tackle this, and if so, how did you solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: I assume that if you try this in a default DNN skin it works correctly? If so I would start by trying to track down issues with your skin.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is a problem with my skin, as the default skin works fine with a long document. Thanks.